# How does Vampiris reanimate the dead?

Tags: books, i-am-legend

I've been reading *[I Am Legend](https://imlegend.fandom.com/wiki/I_Am_Legend)* (1954) by Richard Matheson recently and got to the part where Robert Neville gives himself biology lessons and scientific explanations for vampire behavior, like why they go into a coma in the day, are afraid of crosses, garlic and mirrors, and why they are bulletproof and can only be killed by being stabbed deeply enough. But I found it weird that he doesn't talk about how the bacteria reanimates dead hosts. Did I miss a part where he talks about those things, or does the book just ignore this?

Does the book mention how [Vampiris](https://imlegend.fandom.com/wiki/Vampiris) causes the dead to rise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book does not explain it other than that the bacteria somehow animates the dead body.

> A new idea: What if the bacteria were the strength of the true vampire? He felt a shudder run down his back. Was it possible that the same germ that killed the living provided the energy for the dead?